# Where can I ask this question - Paying Tax In Multiple Countries? | Apple

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where can I ask this question?

> Paying Tax In Multiple Countries? | Apple
>
> I would like to sell my app on the app store (Apple) for an amount of
>   money. If I wanted to sell my app in all of the available countries,
>   what tax do I have to pay and for what countries?
>
> I live in England,
>
> Thanks

EDIT

---

I was told by a moderator on Stack Overflow to ask the question here. I don't see why people don't like the question when an elected moderator told me to do this.

This is what he said:

[image]

Comment: You might be able to ask on https://money.stackexchange.com/, but I'm not sure if your question will be OK or too broad to be an acceptable question on that site.

Comment: Also, most countries have a minimum income threshold before you are taxed, so as long as the income from your app is below that amount you shouldn't have to pay any tax at all.

Comment: Thanks @angussidney , Ill look into that :-)

Comment: I suggest asking this question on Meta Quora :)

Answer (score 2):

[**Money Stack Exchange**](https://money.stackexchange.com) ([mentioned by @angussidney](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300120/where-can-i-ask-this-question-paying-tax-in-multiple-countries-apple#comment975235_300120)) has a few questions from App Store developers about taxes, e.g.

- [How should I report earning from Apple App Store (from iTunes Connect) in Washington state?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/68016/how-should-i-report-earning-from-apple-app-store-from-itunes-connect-in-washin)
- [How does service tax work for Indian app developers selling through an app store?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/71456/how-does-service-tax-work-for-indian-app-developers-selling-through-an-app-store)

so it's probably OK to ask it there, but be sure to read their [help center](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking a question. It does  mention:

> #### Sole Proprietorships
>
> ...
>
> - Taxes as they pertain to an individual's return

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel. After asking on three websites that is the first genuine helpful answer that I have been given.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest posting your question on [Apple Support](https://discussions.apple.com)!

:) That *must* be the right place over the Internet.

Comment: I have tried that and it has been a week with about 150 views and no answer.

Comment: Apple's developer forums ( https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/distribution/app-store ) are probably a better place than their general support forums. The former aren't as cluttered with general software support issues. You can also contact Apple's Banking and Tax team directly via their iTunes Connect contact forms. I've done this in the past for tax-related issues, although this question isn't necessarily specific to Apple but how you handle tax for international software sales in the U.K.

Answer (score 0):

Not all questions fit the Stack Exchange model.
I got a useful answer to my question on Quora. So, sometimes you should ask on another site than Stack Exchange. Like Quora.

Comment: This should be re-phrased a little. You told us you got a useful answer on Quora. So "Quora" is actually an answer to the site-recommendation question. However, as it stands now, people may think you're trolling. Let me see if I can edit this, to make it work better.

Comment: I took the liberty of re-phrasing this in a major way. If you disagree with my edit, you can roll it back - click on the "edited ... ago" above my gravatar for this. I believe, however, that this edit will make your answer better received.

Comment: Still feels a little negative towards SE, seems like the true answer is that, not all questions fit the Stack Exchange model.  There isn't much more to that statement that is required.  The fact there is another Q&E website, named Quora, where this question was answer is besides the point.